# pass data from route to controller that builds multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been trying to implement a feature that has been giving me headaches for days (rails newb).

I have an app that consists of users and the ability to schedule a booking with a special user. I put a "schedule booking" link on the special users profile page that should create (1) A "booking" object and (2) create a child of the booking object (booking.user = special user). This second part is so that only later on only  booking.users will have access to the booking object.

The following is my failed attempt.

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/2/book_person"
```

Rake routes:

```
book_person_user POST /users/:id/book_person(.:format)
```

Route:

```
resources :users do
 member do
  post :book_person, :controller => "bookings", :action => "book_person"
 end
end
```

Booking_controller

```
def book_person
@booking = Booking.new
@booking.name = "Booking with #{params[:id]}"
if @booking.save
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if not @user.participant_of?(@booking)
      @booking.users << @user
      flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully added to booking'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'User was already part of booking'
    end
    redirect_to @booking 
else
  flash[:notice] = "Could not add booking"
  redirect_to @booking
end
```

end

Link on user profile page to book that user:

```
<%= link_to "Book Sessions", book_person_user_path, class: "btn btn-large" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "Book Sessions", book_person_user_path, :method => :post, class: "btn btn-large" %>
```

Comment: worked beautifully! thank you! why do I have to specify `:method => :post` though?

Comment: `No route matches [GET] "/users/2/book_person"` this clearly says your `link_to` is making `GET` request. SO you need to say make `POST` request. Because you added member as `post` method.

Comment: Look at your code in the routes.rb =>  `post :book_person, :controller => "bookings", :action => "book_person".`
You directly said you are going to use the HTTP POST method. If you are not doing any saving action, i.e. saving a object, then use a HTTP GET method (just change the `post` to `get` in your routes.rb), but as i see that you are doing some saving, continue to use the POST method.